# CodeIgniter 2: Is it okay to use header() to call other controller?

Tags: php, http-headers, codeigniter-2

I am currently working on a site that requires a (master) administrator-specific controls. I have two controllers, one is for loading the `login` page, and the other is for loading the `edit_profile` page. Before loading the Edit Profile page, it checks whether the user is logged in or not. And I do it like this:

```
/* edit_profile.php */

<?php if(!$this->session->user_data('logged_in')) header ("Location: " . base_url('login')); ?>
```

I've heard that CI doesn't have ways to call a controller from another. Is it okay to call the other controller like that? Is it bad programming? And if it is one, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

MVC is designed to separate the roles of duties in applications. All presentation, including headers, should be done through a view. This doesn't mean that there is anything wrong with header redirects though, as this is common practice... Secure site? Not logged in? Redirect.

Depending on what your login controller does prior to displaying the view (login forms, etc), you may just be able to load the login view in case of not logged in, and edit_profile view if they are logged in. There are probably quite a few ways to handle this, and each is unique in itself.

What you propose will work, and I can't honestly say there is anything *wrong* with it. It just goes against the design principals of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

What about his? Loading the user details from a model if the user is logged in.

```
function login()
{
    if(!$this->session->user_data('logged_in'))
    {
        $data['msg'] = "Not logged in";
        $this->load->view('login_form',$data);

    } else {

        $data['user_details'] = // call to some sort of user model?     
        $this->load->view('edit_profile',$data);
    }           
}
```